# PHP: Take multiple values from the same form

Tags: php

i have a form, i need to show form's entries before send it to database
i mean when the user submits the form i want to show the values entered and the form be ready to take another sets of entries. let's say the user enters 10 , 20 entries to the form and then have a send button to send the data into database. i designed the front of what i want i hope it whould help : [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Visq3.jpg)

here is what crossed my mind to do it whit a foreach but i couldn't pull it off successfully

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    ESM: <input type="text" required name="name"><br><br><br>
    FAMIL: <input type="text" name="family"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $family = $_REQUEST['family'];
    $names = array();
    
    foreach ($name as $index => $names) {
        $names = $name[$index];
        echo $names . " - " . $family;
    }
    
    echo "your name is " . $name . " " . $family;
    
} 
?>
```

if you just could do it for a form of 2 inputs i will figure it out the rest :)
much appreciate your help

Comment: If you need to do this before you submit the form then you'll have to display the data on your table through javascript and then submit the form through javascript. You'll need a onSubmit() function that will do all this.

Comment: I think you mean `name="name[]"` the `[]` makes that field an array, bu t you will have to output 10 of them, or write javascript to add a new row dynamically to the page

Comment: You need to use Ajax (client-side).

Comment: thanks. yes sir i wanted to store form values in an array, show the array in table and then send the array values in database columns. (i don't know if it's technically doable?) sadly i don't know javascript :( do you know any reference i can learn javascript real quick?

Comment: It is possible. You'll need **JS/JQuery** to handle showing data in client-side, and **PHP** `$_POST[ ]` will handle sending data to database.

Comment: tnx NcXNav. do you have any reference of this topic in JS that can help me?

Comment: Hey @hosenalipoor, you can google `how to add/remove rows in html with JavaScript`. There are plenty of examples. I've created a simple `add/remove table row` back then, maybe you can refer and start from this [code](https://codepen.io/navenoc13/pen/BaRxVPQ). After you can do this add/remove dynamically, then you proceed to learn how to handle <input> with array field name `name=inputName[]`. Break it down to smaller steps and you'll get it there soon, goodluck!

Comment: much appreciate bro :) u've helped a lot